# boost::asio::signal_set does not restore previous signal handlers

Tags: c++, signals, boost-asio

So I have a daemon who can be gracefully shut down using `SIGQUIT`. 
This daemon is running `boost::asio::io_service`. I use `boost::asio::signal_set` to catch this signal.

I have encountered a behaviour that I believe to be completely wrong. When I destroy `boost::asio::signal_set` object it does not restore previous handler of that signal. Previous handler for `SIGQUIT` was a no-op. So upon receiving this signal after `boost::asio::signal_set` was destroyed my daemon terminates. My guess is this is because `boost::asio::signal_set` upon destruction sets default handler, that is to terminate the program, but not the previous handler.

I see this as very inappropriate. What I am asking is am I wrong? Maybe I am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost.Asio does not specify the resulting handler state for a signal that had been added to [`boost::asio::signal_set`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/signal_set.html) and then removed via either `signal_set::remove()`, `signal_set::clear()`, or destruction of the `signal_set`.  In particular, the post-condition is not specified for any of the associated operations in the [Signal Set Service requirements](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/SignalSetService.html).

A quick glance a the [`signal_set_service::add()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/signal_set_service/add.html) [implementation](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/4f11be277a7182d83a545fc4d37a92489ce4c0bc/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/signal_set_service.ipp#L279):

```cpp
::sigaction(signal_number, &sa, 0)
```

and the [`signal_set_service::clear()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/signal_set_service/clear.html) [implementation](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/4f11be277a7182d83a545fc4d37a92489ce4c0bc/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/signal_set_service.ipp#L400-L403):

```cpp
struct sigaction sa;
memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
sa.sa_handler = SIG_DFL;
::sigaction(reg->signal_number_, &sa, 0)
```

shows that the calls to [`sigaction()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sigaction.html) are not handling previously installed handlers, and results in the default handler action being registered when a signal is removed via `signal_set_service`.

---

As a signal may be delivered after Boost.Asio sets the signal action to default, but before the application code has been able to assign its own handler, consider using [`pthread_sigmask()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_sigmask.html) to block all signals within the `io_service`.  Once the signals have been removed from the `signal_set`, assign the desired handler via `sigaction()`, then unblock the signals.

Here is a complete example demonstrating this approach:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

void signal_handler(int signal_number)
{
  std::cout << "signal_handler(): " << signal_number << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  // Force scope to control io_service lifetime.
  {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    // Boost.Asio will register an internal handler for SIGQUIT.
    boost::asio::signal_set signal_set(io_service, SIGQUIT);
    signal_set.async_wait(
      [](const boost::system::error_code& error,
         int signal_number)
      {
        std::cout << "siganl_set.async_wait handler: " 
                  << signal_number << std::endl;

        // Block SIGQUIT.
        sigset_t signal_mask;
        sigemptyset(&signal_mask);
        sigaddset(&signal_mask, SIGQUIT);
        assert(pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &signal_mask, NULL) == 0);
      });

    // Send SIGQUIT to this process.
    raise(SIGQUIT);
    // By the time raise() returns, Boost.Asio has handled SIGQUIT with its
    // own internal handler, queuing it internally.  At this point, Boost.Asio
    // is ready to dispatch this notification to a user signal handler 
    // (i.e. those provided to signal_set.async_wait()) within the
    // io_service event loop.

    // Prior to calling the io_service, SIGQUIT is not blocked.
    io_service.run();
    // The user provided handler was invoked and has blocked SIGQUIT.
  }

  // Send SIGQUIT to this process.
  raise(SIGQUIT);
  // Even though Boost.Asio has set the default handler for SIGQUIT, the
  // signal is blocked, so the signal has been placed into a pending state.

  // Register a custom handler for SIGQUIT.
  struct sigaction sa;
  sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
  sa.sa_handler = &signal_handler;
  assert(sigaction(SIGQUIT, &sa, 0) == 0);

  // Unblock SIGQUIT.
  sigset_t signal_mask;
  sigemptyset(&signal_mask);
  sigaddset(&signal_mask, SIGQUIT);
  assert(pthread_sigmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &signal_mask, NULL) == 0);
  // Upon unblocking, the pending SIGQUIT signal is delivered and handled
  // by the handler registered via sigaction.

  std::cout << "Fin" << std::endl;
}
```

And its output:

```
$ ./a.out 
siganl_set.async_wait handler: 3
signal_handler(): 3
Fin
```

Comment: I see this as a strange behaviour to not to restore old sigaction object. Very very strange. Thank you for help! The with signal blocking will probably be the only reliable way out of this.